# Add Facebook og tags in cakephp subdomain sites

Tags: facebook, cakephp, meta-tags

I am working with various sub-domain of cakephp.
For example, main domain is : www.example.com
Various sub-domains may be: abc.example.com, def.example.com

In each sub-domain, there is courses page. I want to share each course page for each sub-domain.

I can't directly add facebook og meta tags in  of layouts->default.ctp file because each course page has its own image.

I have done as following:

In view file:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('description', $course['Course']['summary']);

    echo $this->Html->meta(array('property' => 'og:title', 'type' => 'meta', 'content' => $course['Course']['fullname'], 'rel' => null));
    echo $this->Html->meta(array('property' => 'og:url', 'type' => 'meta', 'content' => Configure::read('http').Configure::read('storeName').'.'.Configure::read('site_lms').'Course/view/'.$course['Course']['id'], 'rel' => null));
    echo $this->Html->meta(array('property' => 'og:description', 'type' => 'meta', 'content' => $course['Course']['summary'], 'rel' => null));
    echo $this->Html->meta(array('property' => 'og:image', 'type' => 'meta', 'content' => $courseimage_fb, 'rel' => null));
    echo $this->Html->meta(array('property' => 'og:type', 'type' => 'meta', 'content' => 'website', 'rel' => null));
?>
```

And in default.ctp file of layouts folder:

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('meta'); ?>
```

when I see source of page, then meta tags are displaying in body of page.

When I share page url on Facebook, then it shows random images. Sometimes correct and sometimes incorrect image. There are other images in page like logo and banner.

What is wrong here? Whether I am missing any javascript file for facebook share or any other meta tag? Please help.

Comment: Did you check here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked with this tool:  It is also saying:                       Errors That Must Be Fixed:
"Meta Tags In Body Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable."

Comment: In next, tool saying:                                                 Warnings That Should Be Fixed"
"Inferred Property The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."

Comment: “Meta Tags In Body” usually means that you have errors in your HTML code – so go validate that first. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Solved. Meta tags are now displaying in head tag by adding two more parameters. Meta tags should be written like this:                                           <?php

    echo $this->Html->meta(array('property' => 'og:title', 'type' => 'meta', 'content' => $course['Course']['fullname']), null, array('inline' => false));
    
?>